# Sharing BIO between parent and chid while avoiding the shutdown()

Tags: linux, sockets, openssl

I am using the OpenSSL BIO_... functions to create a connection which is either secure or not. The basics work just fine, whether the connection is encrypted or not (i.e. I can communicate using the `BIO_read()` and `BIO_write()` functions, just as expected.)

However, when I want to create a child, it is customary to close sockets we are not going to use in the parent or the child. I can solve the child problem by marking the socket with SOCK_CLOEXEC. However, if I want to do the opposite, keep the socket open in the child and close it in the parent I run in a problem: the `BIO_free_all()` function calls `shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR)` before the `close(s)`. The result after that is that the socket is dead (effectively, shutdown...) in the child as well.

My question is: is there a way to properly share an OpenSSL BIO interface between parent and child by avoiding the `shutdown()` call?

If not in the BIO interface itself, I can always close the file descriptor before calling `BIO_free_all()`, but that sounds like an ugly hack!

Comment: You should call BIO_free_all in the parent only after the child is forked. Close and shutdown of a socket (or any other kind of file descriptor) in the parent will not have any effect in the child. But you should not call SSL_shutdown in the parent.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, that's not correct. I just wrote a test, if the parent (or child) does `close()` only, we're good. If the parent (or child) does `shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR)` and `close(s)` on the socket, then the socket is dead after that, for both, the parent and the child.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich `shutdown(..., SHUT_WR)` will send a FIN to the peer, and make it impossible for anyone to send anything over this socket again. It isn't confined to the parent.

Comment: @EJP: thanks for clarification. Then there is probably no other way as to `close()` the socket before calling BIO_free_all(). Interestingly I've never stumbled over this problem - maybe because I use the `SSL_*` functions and not the `BIO_*` functions.